# Regression with "unidirectional" noise

Tags: regression

I would like to learn a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ from data $(x_i, y_i)$ where $y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$. $\epsilon_i$ can be seen as observation noise; however, it is always smaller or equal to 0 ($\epsilon_i \leq 0$), i.e., the observations are always a lower bound on the true function value. Are there any regression approaches particularly suited for this setting? Is it required to make specific assumptions regarding the distribution of $\epsilon_i$?

Comment: Do you know the form of $f(x)$? Can $\epsilon$ get close to $0$?

Comment: Do you have multiple replicates at each observed level of $x_i$?

Comment: I don't know the specific form of $f(x)$. $\epsilon$ might get close to (or even become) $0$. Typically, I would not have multiple replicates at each observed level of $x_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This set up is equivalent to the ***Deterministic* (Efficiency/Productivity) Frontier Analysis** in Econometrics, where the econometrician is trying to measure how far a firm/unit of production is from full-efficiency in the utilization of production factors. The $f(x)$ function is the full-efficiency production function (i.e. it gives maximum output given technology and inputs $x$, the "production frontier") and the error embodies a measurement of the distance of actual output from the theoretical maximum,

$$q_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i,\;\; \epsilon_i\le 0$$

This model has been largely abandoned, because in it, *one of the regularity conditions for maximum likelihood estimation is violated*: since $\epsilon_i\le 0$ we have always

$$q_i \le f(x_i)$$
which makes the *range* (i.e. the support) of the random variable $q_i$ (actual production) dependent on the parameters to be estimated (that are included in $f(x_i)$). Then the standard asymptotic properties of maximum likelihood estimators cannot be invoked, i.e. it is unknown whether they hold or not.

So it has been replaced by the **Stochastic Frontier** framework, where alongside the one-sided error-term, a zero-mean symmetric disturbance (usually assumed normal) is added (that represents chance effects on the output of the firm that are not related to the "internal efficiency" of the firm):

$$q_i = f(x_i) + u_i+\epsilon_i,\;\; E(u_i\mid x_i) = 0,\;\;\epsilon_i\le 0$$

which deals with the issue mentioned above (and it is after all, more realistic also). Can you augment your model also, by adding a symmetric zero-mean error? Then the machinery of ML estimation is already in place in the Stochastic Frontier literature, with more than one stochastic specifications worked out.

Comment: I didn't know the Stochastic Frontier framework. Sounds promising. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I tried implementing a simplified version of this using pymc but did not succeed yet. I posted a follow-up question on this under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194587/regression-with-unidirectional-noise

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with code. Stochastic frontier models are almost always estimated by Maximum Likelihood, after making a distributional assumption. The symmetric error term is assumed always normal, and the asymmetric error term is assumed, half-normal, exponential, or gamma. The density of the composite error  has been derived for these cases (in the case of a half-normal it is  a skew normal density), and researchers implement them directly in the context of ML estimation.

Comment: Right, I will probably implement the ML estimation myself. Thanks for your answer!